# Export to PDF with LibreOffice command-line, selecting an output filename

Tags: command-line, pdf, libreoffice, headless

This works to export a PDF:

```
C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf test.doc --outdir .
```

but it doesn't allow to change the output *filename*. I found the option to change the output directory, but **how to change the output filename?**

Answer (score 0):

Just rename it after it saves. it will be the exact name with .pdf on the end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to directly do this. Instead (elaborating on the answer provided by JJ_Coder4Hire), as a workaround, one might create a dedicated output directory and and then rename the file generated by `soffice`:

```
mkdir /tmp/soffice_output_dir
soffice --headless --convert-to odt  --outdir /tmp/soffice_output_dir xyz.html
mv /tmp/soffice_output_dir/xyz.odt /path/to/the_desired_name.odt
```